# How to import excel file to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net

This is the code i got it only import excel to datagridview. how do i import excel to mysql database using vb.net?

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + TextBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
End Sub
```

Comment: There is nothing there related to MySQL, so have you tried nothing?

Comment: The truth is i don't know where i should begin

Comment: Well, that means this is too broad and you need to do more research.  I know for a fact there are a number of posts here (50k+) to import from one thing to another (not always excel or MySQL but the *concepts* are there).

Answer (score 0):

No matter you use VB or other language.

- Read you file, and loop over
- You just need to transform the excel `column_title` to to have a string like `(column1, column2, column3, ...)`
- Then every excel row to concatenated values_variable :

> ```
> (value1, value2, value3, ...), 
> (value1, value2, value3, ...),
> (value1, value2, value3, ...)
> ```

- So, you just need to create an INSERT query at the end of the loop:

> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES 
>   (value1, value2, value3, ...),  (value1, value2, value3, ...),
>   (value1, value2, value3, ...), ... ;

Comment: can you give me another example?

Comment: see sample code for import [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/importing-exporting-excel-271e96d5)